# Knockout, unable to parse Binding error in empty observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have this error

```
Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined;
Bindings value: text:SomeArray().length
```

I have recreated the error in here.

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12758/

```
var somevalue = [{Test:[]}]; // this is not always blank, but i cannot control it.
var ViewModel = function() {
     this.SomeArray=ko.observableArray(somevalue.Test);   
};

<span data-bind="text:SomeArray().length"></span>
<!-- ko if: SomeArray().length>0 -->
Hello World!
<!-- /ko -->
```

using

```
<!-- ko if: SomeArray() -->
Hello World!
<!-- /ko -->
```

doesn't creates the error but also doesn't skip the "Hello World" Message when the array is blank.
i need to check if the array is blank and display the message only if not blank.

I can't use `foreach` because i am not looping though the array but just checking if it is blank only.

Comment: somevalue is an **array**! Your assigment in your viewmodel is wrong: it should be `somevalue[0].Test` http://jsfiddle.net/CB5Tz/

Comment: oh. Then are there any other methods than length ko check for empty array?

Comment: length is perfectly fine for check array emptiness. But you initialize your `SomeArray` property with `somevalue.Test` which is **undefined**. So your `SomeArray` property **does not contains an array** therefore your `SomeArray().length` call throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somevalue is an array. So somevalue.Test is not defined but somevalue[0].Test will return [].

```
this.SomeArray=ko.observableArray(somevalue[0].Test);
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12759/)

Comment: oh. Then are there any other methods than length ko check for empty array?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please explain what you are trying to do ?